# Force GraphViz force align between subgraph

Tags: nodes, graphviz, subgraph

I use GraphViz with the following dot file:

```
digraph "Fast-forward"
{
    rankdir=LR;
    subgraph master
    {
        "5c071a6b2c" -> "968bda3251";
    }
    subgraph branch
    {
        "35ee8ce6b6" [color="blue"] [style="filled"];
        "968bda3251" -> "9754d40473" [weight=0];
        "9754d40473" -> "9e59700d33" -> "35ee8ce6b6";
    }
    subgraph c1
    {
        rankdir=LR;
        rank="same";
        "remote/master/HEAD" [shape=box];
        "remote/master/HEAD" -> "35ee8ce6b6" [weight=0];
        oldmh [label="master/HEAD"] [shape=box] [color="red"] [style="filled"];
        newmh [label="master/HEAD"] [shape=box] [color="blue"] [style="filled"];
        oldmh -> "968bda3251" [weight=0];
        newmh -> "35ee8ce6b6" [weight=0];
    }
}
```

It give me something like that:
[image: Bag thing]

But I want something like that:

> ```
>                                                      white
>                                                         |
>                                                        \/
>                      "9754d40473" -> "9e59700d33" -> "35ee8ce6b6";
>                      /                                  /\
> ```
>
> 5c071a6b2c -> 968bda3251
>
> ```
>              /\                                         |
>               |
>             red                                       blue
> ```

How can I do that?

For your help,
Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to define all the nodes with special needs (like being in the same rank or having special shapes/colors) first, then define the links.  That way, you're assured that the `rank=same` nodes are correctly grouped, and defined in the right order.

Without `weight=0`, all the side links end up on the top.  Add `weight=0` to the ones you want on the bottom.

```
digraph "Fast-forward"
{
    rankdir=LR;
    subgraph c1 {
        rank="same";
        "968bda3251";
        oldmh [label="master/HEAD"] [shape=box] [color="red"] [style="filled"];
    }
    subgraph c2
    {
        rank="same";
        "remote/master/HEAD" [shape=box];
        "35ee8ce6b6" [color="blue"] [style="filled"];
        newmh [label="master/HEAD"] [shape=box] [color="blue"] [style="filled"];
    }
    "5c071a6b2c" -> "968bda3251" -> "9754d40473" -> "9e59700d33" -> "35ee8ce6b6";
    oldmh -> "968bda3251" [weight=0];
    "remote/master/HEAD" -> "35ee8ce6b6";
    newmh -> "35ee8ce6b6" [weight=0];
}
```

[image: The results from dot]

If you really want that jog between 96 and 97, you can do it this way:

```
digraph "Fast-forward"
{
    rankdir=LR;
    subgraph c1 {
        rank=same;
        "968bda3251";
        oldmh [label="master/HEAD"] [shape=box] [color="red"] [style="filled"];
    }
    subgraph c1p5 {
        rank=same;
        "9754d40473";
        inviso [style="invis"];
    }
    subgraph c2
    {
        rank="same";
        "remote/master/HEAD" [shape=box];
        "35ee8ce6b6" [color="blue"] [style="filled"];
        newmh [label="master/HEAD"] [shape=box] [color="blue"] [style="filled"];
    }
    "5c071a6b2c" -> "968bda3251";
    "968bda3251" -> "9754d40473" [weight=0];
    "9754d40473" -> "9e59700d33" -> "35ee8ce6b6";
    oldmh -> "968bda3251" [weight=0];
    "remote/master/HEAD" -> "35ee8ce6b6";
    newmh -> "35ee8ce6b6" [weight=0];
    "968bda3251" -> inviso [style="invis"];
    "9754d40473" -> inviso [style="invis"];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`rank="same"` effects all nodes of a subgraph, so you have to split your labelling subgraph in two parts:

```
digraph "Fast-forward"
{
    rankdir=LR;
    subgraph master
    {
        "5c071a6b2c" -> "968bda3251";
    }
    subgraph branch
    {
        "968bda3251" -> "9754d40473" [weight=0];
        "9754d40473" -> "9e59700d33" -> "35ee8ce6b6";
        "35ee8ce6b6" [color="blue"] [style="filled"];
    }
    subgraph c1
    {
        rank="same";
        "remote/master/HEAD" [shape=box];
        "remote/master/HEAD" -> "35ee8ce6b6" [weight=0];
        newmh [label="master/HEAD"] [shape=box] [color="blue"] [style="filled"];
        newmh -> "35ee8ce6b6" [weight=0];
    }
    subgraph c2
    {
        rank="same";
        oldmh [label="master/HEAD"] [shape=box] [color="red"] [style="filled"];
        oldmh -> "968bda3251" [weight=0];
    }
}
```

This will give you:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have realized that my 'asciiart' isn't printed correctly, is it possible to put remote/master/HEAD on the top? Thanks by advance.

Comment: Try moving subgraph c2 above subgraph c1.  The order of definition of nodes can affect the order that they are displayed in on the resulting graph.  It isn't a guarantee, but it might work.  **never mind, didn't work.  I'll look at it some more.**