# Forcing subgraphs to align with newrank=true

Tags: graphviz

Here is my graph:

[image: graph]

Is it possible to shift the "User-facing options" subgraph downward, so that "User-facing content" is above both that subgraph and the "Internal tags" subgraph? I tried using the technique described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18410951/2954547 to force either `topic` or `role` to align with `tag`, but for some reason it really really wants to put the other node in that subgraph *above* the `tag` node, and not below it.

I see that you can also mess with the `weight` parameter to adjust the output, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14348263/2954547, but this just made the lines shorter and longer.

My desired output is to shift the left subgraph like so:

[image: desired graph]

Current source code:

```
digraph G {
  compound=true;
  newrank=true;

  subgraph cluster_userFacing {
    label="User-facing options";
    labelloc="bottom";
    role [label="User Role\n(User Classification)"];
    topic [label="Topic\n(External Tag)"];
  }

  subgraph cluster_content {
    label="User-facing Content";
    article [label="Article"];
    podcastEpisode [label="Podcast Episode"];
  }
  
  subgraph cluster_internal {
    label="Internal tags";
    labelloc="bottom";
    tag [label="Tag\n(Internal Tag)"];
    tagCategory [label="Tag Category"];
    tag -> tagCategory;
  }

  role -> tag [dir="none"];
  topic -> tag [dir="none"];

  article -> tag;
  podcastEpisode -> tag;
  
  { rank="min"; podcastEpisode; article; }
  
  { rank="same"; topic; tag; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclosed the two clusters inside a new invisible (peripheries=0) cluster.
Set constraint=false to override ranking.  And added an invisible edge.

```
digraph G {

  node [height=.78]  // make all nodes same height
  subgraph clusterGroup{
    peripheries=0
  subgraph cluster_userFacing {
    peripheries=1
    label="User-facing options";
    labelloc="bottom";
    role [label="User Role\n(User Classification)" ]
    topic [label="Topic\n(External Tag)"];
  }
  subgraph cluster_internal {
    peripheries=1
    label="Internal tags";
    labelloc="bottom";
    tag [label="Tag\n(Internal Tag)" group=G];
    tagCategory [label="Tag Category"]; 
    tag -> tagCategory;
  }
 }

  subgraph cluster_content {
    label="User-facing Content";
    article [label="Article" ]
    podcastEpisode [label="Podcast Episode" group=G];
  }
  role  -> tag  [dir="none" constraint=false];
  topic -> tag  [dir="none" constraint=false];
  article -> tag  
  podcastEpisode -> tag;

  role -> topic [style=invis]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: That's quite messy. I love the basic Dot language, but it's sometimes very annoying how you have to go through these contortions to goad the layout engine produce good results.